# Error converting data type varchar to numeric (when there is no conversion needed) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

There is no conversion in my code. Code is very long due to the variables but shortened looks like this.

```
Select 
        Var1,
        Var2,
        Var3
into #newtable
from #mainT
union all
select 
       var1,
       var2,
       varX as var3
from #Sup1
union all....
```

This coding repeats to union all 1 main table and 6 supplemental tables. All of the tables have the same variables that are formatted as the same type. They are all around 50 million observations. When I did a test run on a smaller subset (1 million each) the code ran no problem. However, when I run the with the full table size the code errors out "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" on the first select line. This makes no sense to me since they are all the same type of variable.

Has anyone seen this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: They are not all the same type.  If they were, you would not be getting a type conversion error.

Comment: Please provide a small sample of the data and table structures.

Comment: My issue is why work on a small subset of the same data and then report an error on the full set. Weird thing is if I take out one of the supplemental tables it works (doesn't matter which one). All the variable types are the same I have confirmed this before I use the union all.

Comment: We would really need to see the data, perhaps you can try using filters to locate the rows that cause the error, try selecting the large sub-set, then apply filters to gradually reduce the size of the set until you can isolate the specific rows that are the problem

Comment: `All of the tables have the same variables that are formatted as the same type.` This could be your issue, if you show us the syntax, we might be able to identify potential expressions that can throw this type of error, hint it will be an expression that tries to format as a numeric output.

Comment: check the datatypes for #main1,#sup1 in the metadata tables. In SQL-SERVER this would be from tempdb.information_schema.columns where table_name like '#main%'